# Upload file synchronously

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Is there a way to upload a file synchronously?

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 for my web app and since the file sizes will always be relatively small (< 100kb), the waiting time is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Drive API supports synchronous file uploads.

Check the `files.insert` method in the Reference guide for more details: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

The snippet below is taken from the documentation:

```
...
FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, mimeType);
request.Upload();

File file = request.ResponseBody;
...
```

The call to `request.Upload` will return when the upload is completed and `request.ResponseBody` will contain the file metadata from the response.

Comment: I was looking for a method within the Google Documents List API.

Comment: Take the sample at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_a_new_document_or_file_with_both_metadata_and_content and use uploader.Insert() instead of uploader.InsertAsync()

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it. My bad for not finding it.